# IFERROR(formula,"") passing #N/A instead of ""

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When I apply the following array formula over 7 rows, it returns #N/A for rows 6 and 7.  Why is it not using "" instead?

```
=IFERROR(ROW(A1:A5),"")
```

when I check with iserror(A6 or A7) it reports true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the logic behind. What does the `IFERROR` do? it replaces the error entries in the given array, by the second parameter.

> ```
> =IFERROR(ROW(A1:A5),"")
> ```

will generate an array with 5 values. There is no error above, but if you were using a range possibly containing errors and NA's, such as

> ```
> =IFERROR(A1:A5,"")
> ```

The `IFERROR` function will replace the error entries in the given array, by `""`. That's all. It **will not change the size of the array**.

At the end you are getting an array with 5 entries. Entries beyond dont get any values from the array. That's why `#N/A` is displayed.